# If `SIM` state is `NETWORK_LOCKED`, How can I unlock it programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-source, telephonymanager, sim-card

I have a tool, using that I can able to network lock and then can do unlock manually, but I need to do unlock programmatically, How ?

Below is just for Information more understanding :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED

if you share snippet of code or source code links are appreciated, Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Android Applications are not allowed to unlock the SIM-Card. There are System apps available on all phones to handle this. You could look for the appropriate activity/application and start it via an Intent so the user could enter their PIN.

Comment: Thanks for quick response,I already searched for the way from long back but no luck. Please Let me know what is the activity/application to unlock and How to start/call it from my application ?

Comment: I can't confirm this right now but I think the PIN-Input will be visible when opening the dialer Activity.